# MacOS - Load dynamic library from other dylib

Tags: macos, dylib

I would like to hijack a program that uses a dynamic library. This library is very important to the program, so I want to make sure it still gets loaded. What I want to do is create a replica dylib that calls the original dylib, and adds its own code. I do not want to mess with System Integrity Protection.By the way, this program is Firefox.I want to hack libnss3.dylib

Comment: Sounds vaguely evil.

Comment: @matt stop you will blow my cover! :0

Comment: I suspect you could create a dylib with the same name/signature at a custom location, then set one of the dynamic library search path environment variables so it would find your library first. See [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html). Your library would than have to find the original and pass all requests through. And yes, this does sound evil.

Comment: Actually, I would like to create this library on the same directory, and rename the original.